# Group ring $\Bbb Z[G]$ has zero divisors

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification

Let $G$ be a non-trivial finite group. Show that $\Bbb Z[G]$ has got zero divisors.

Let $g\in G$, $g\neq 0_G$, we have  that $0 (g) \cdot 2022(g^{-1})=(0 \cdot 2022)(g\cdot g^{-1})=0\cdot 0_G=0_{\Bbb Z[G]}$. Both $0 (g)$ and  $2022(g^{-1})$ are not zero so they are zero divisors. Is it enough ? I did not use the fact that $G$ is finite. Did I misunderstand something ?

Comment: Since the group $G$ is finite then every element has  a finite order. For instance consider $g\in G$ different from $0_{G}$ has order $n$ then $1-g$ is a zero divisor. Why?

Comment: @Liddo I see why but is my proof wrong ?

Comment: I note that $0\cdot g=0_{Z[G]}$ why is not a zero divisor because you are multiplying by zero

Comment: I am talking about the element (singleton in $Z[G]$) $0(g)$ not about $0_Z[G] \cdot 1(g)$

Comment: My teacher gave a wrong definition of group ring. I understand now.

Comment: To avoid confusion, the identity element of $G$ should be denoted $1_G$ or $e_G$, not $0_G$.